# Is there some function so that a choice in a variable does not get replaced by another choice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, python-re

for a constant called M, i created a module called constants and wrote the value of M inside:

```
from random import choice
l1 = ['a',
      'ability',
      'able',
      'about',
      'above',
      'accept',
      'according'
      'account'
      'across',
      'act',
      'action',
      'activity',
      'actually',
      'add',
      'address',
      'administration',
      'admit',
      'adult',
      'affect',
      'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
      'yes,'
      'Good Morning',
      'Good night',
      'Super Ball'
      ]
M = choice(l1)
```

And I tried to import it but when I tried:

```
import datetime
import re

from constants import M

print('''
Welcome to Typing Practice!
We will give some random text.
You should type it again.
The time took will be printed.
Your time starts... NOW!!!
''')

print(f'You must enter {M}')
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
h = input("")


n = re.compile(r'M')
errors = 0
for letter in M:
    if not n.match(h):
        errors += 1


time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_took = time_now - current_time
print("you took: ", time_took, "\n\\\\\\", "Errors:", errors)
```

I simply got
You must enter act
I entered
act
and it said:
\\ Errors: 3
That probably means M is changing!!

```
                             -----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.compile(r'M')` is literally making a regular expression which matches the string "M".  As in, you'd have to type M on your keyboard to match it.

Don't use regex for this.  Just iterate over the input string and the string variable `M` and compare the characters in a simple `for` loop.